# How to fix width in tooltipster

Tags: jquery-plugins

Could someone advise a newbie on how I can fix the width in tooltipster.

This is what I have at the moment in the head of my document

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
        fixedWidth: 250                 
    });
</script>
```

Many thanks
IanC

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, there's an error in your setup of your Tooltipster tooltip:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster();
    fixedWidth: 250
```

Needs to be:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({fixedWidth: 250});
```

This passes a JSON object (which contains your 'setup') to the `tooltipster()` function. This should solve the issues you're having.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I tried and it's not working...instead maxWidth works...I don't know why (of course I tried not with both attributes together)